# Nexus 7, Nexus 4 NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I know they can read NFC tags. But can this devices write to NFC tags? Do you someone one of this devices? Any experience with NFC tags? Thx for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read from and write to tags, also using these devices(or most of the NFC Enabled Smart Devices), you can create peer to peer communication between those.

Android documentation about NFC is quite nice http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

Also, have a look at this link to read & write to tags
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#read-write

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both devices can also write NFC tags. You need additional software. Browse for nfc on Google Play.